# Analyze the time complexity of the following for loop

Tags: performance, algorithm, runtime, sum, time-complexity

I need help with the following problem:

for i <- 5 to m do P(i)

where P(i) is executed (m-i) times provided m >= 3

I realize that this is the summation [image]

But I'm not sure exactly how to calculate the run time from this. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you explain what P(i) is?

Comment: Shouldn't that be that P(i) executes (m-i) times provided m >= **i**? I don't see how it could execute a negative number of times! Also, is it right that P(i) takes O(1) time if m &lt; i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count complexity of `P(i)` as constant, then you have just loop `m - 5` times - it will give you complexity `O(m)`

Comment: Yes P(i) is being counted as a constant, thank you.